# How to type cast of a session object into a class object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

i have a class called user. I put that class object into session. My question is, how can i retrieve that object into another page?

```
var user = obj.user;
var username = obj.username;
var name = obj.cn;
var title = obj.title;
var department = obj.department;
User obj= new User();
Session["User"] = obj;
```

Another Page:

Index.cshtml

```
<div>
<h4> Hi @  i need the username here </h4>
<h4> i need department here</h4>
</div>
```

help me to access the session object.

Comment: asp.net core? For scalability `ISession` only really stores byte arrays. Though you can serialise any POCO as UTF8 json.

Comment: `User obj = (User)Session["User"];`

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
No, i am working in Asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

In your view,use

```
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
  <h4>@Context.Session.GetString("User")</h4>
```

or you can pass Session["User"] into a TempData variable and catch that TempData variable into your index method .so that you can access it into your view.

Comment: Hi, Thank you.
User isn't a single session variable here.
it's an object of a class. 
User is an object of a class and i keep that object in session.
and finally i need to retrieve the object's field value.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have found the solution but if not you can simple do this step at the top of the view

```
`@{ User u = (User)Session["User"];}`
```

then on page you can simple call any where like **Full Name: @u.FullName**